# How to run Update Database using Code first in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, aspnetboilerplate

I run the `Update-Database` from visual studio to create a database, it works fine. I have published the app on a production server. But I cannot run `Update-Database` there. So how it can be done on the server where there is no visual studio?

I thought to create it when the application starts the first time. But I didn't get any reference or sample code.

I'm using .net core 2.0.

Comment: Maybe this can help you?  https://abelsquidhead.com/index.php/2017/07/31/deploying-dbs-in-your-cicd-pipeline-with-ef-core-code-first/ or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42620427/auto-migration-in-ef-core-in-three-tier-application

Comment: Getting error InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'MyProject.EntityFrameworkCore.MyDbContext' while attempting to activate 'MyProject.Web.Host.Startup.Startup'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I want to warn you that I do not know what consequences the following code may have, since I do not know enough about the Abp architecture.

In the ProjectName.Web.Mvc project, in the ConfigureServices method, add the following code:

```cs
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

    // other stuff

    string connectionString = _appConfiguration
            .GetConnectionString("Default");

    services.AddDbContext<YouDbContextTypeName>(opt => 
        opt.UseSqlServer(connectionString)
    );

    // other stuff
}
```

In the same file in the Configure method, add the following code:

```cs
public void Configure(
    IApplicationBuilder app, 
    IHostingEnvironment env, 
    YouDbContextTypeName context) {

    context.Database.Migrate();

    // other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run the change scripts made against your development Db in your say 'Test' Db.  To generate the scripts you can run this which creates a file to run as say part of your deployment phase.

```
dotnet ef migrations script -i -o "C:\<your-path>\<your-filename>.sql"
```

The script generated is essentially a cumulation of all the 'Up' migrations. The script is 'idempotent' in that it only applies migrations if they haven't already been applied to the database.

REF: [dotnet CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet)